# Add new ASP.NEt server controls with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a set of fields that are repeated on a form. They are simply 3 input boxes. I have a link at the bottom of the set that says "Add More." When clicked, I use .append() in jQuery to write out a new row of input fields (and name them something unique). The problem is I am adding HTML fields, not ASP.NET server controls.

How do I access these in my code behind since they are not seen on the form until runtime (that is, runtime in the browser)?

-Chris

Comment: Hi Chris, I have a similar situation here, you mentioned about that you solved this problem by using ListView template column. But how did you retrieve the user input value from these dynamically generated textboxes. Thanks & Regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is fundamentally impossible.

jQuery runs purely on the client, whereas ASP.Net server-side controls exist primarily on the server.

Instead, you can communicate with server-side code using jQuery by putting information in hidden fields.

Consider switching to ASP.Net MVC, which is much better at this sort of thing.

Comment: I don't have the ability to switch to MVC... not my project, not my decision. I was able to accomplish what I wanted by using a ListView template column.

Comment: @ee99ee: Do you have an example of how you did that? I'd love to see it.

Comment: Why not use the jQuery .get function to display the contents of the asp.net control in an html iframe?

Comment: @MichaelDark: That won't work with ASP.Net server controls and ViewState.  Also, `<iframe>`s and AJAX are basicallly opposites.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can to it!

Well, you cannot really add "server controls", but you can certainly add input boxes client side, post it and read their values server side.

Assume you add the following input client side:

```
<input type="text" id="textbox_id" name="textbox_name" />
```

The input and its value will be sent in the request to the server, so server side code to access it would be:

```
string value = Request.Form["textbox_name"];
```

Answer (score 1):

As SLaks said, this is fundamentally impossible.  However, one workaround would be to "compress" all your dynamic fields into one hidden field which is itself an ASP.NET control.  For example, you could set a form submit handler in jQuery which would serialize your dynamic form fields into a JSON string and set your ASP.NET hidden field to that value.  Obviously, your back-end would have to de-serialize it and process it accordingly, as would your front-end when you load the page.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of ways that you could do this. I'm assuming by "3 input boxes", you mean 3 `TextBox` controls:

1. Add more `TextBox` controls to begin with in the markup, and hide the extra ones until the user clicks "Add more". This would be suitable if there was a reasonable upper-bound to how many controls you want the user to be allowed to add.
2. Before postback, take the values of the newly added controls, and place them in a hidden field. The server will be able to read the values from there.
3. Communicate the values of the controls to the server via AJAX.

I'm sure that there are other ways to accomplish this as well, but I think that one of these three will work for you.