# How to dynamically create and add textbox to a placeholder using AJAX?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to create text box dynamically. so I cal  it through the AJAX function.

This is my code:

**Ajax function**

```
function ChangedAdults(noofAdults) {
    alert(noofAdults.value);
    $.ajax({

        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "/FlightBooking.aspx/Adults",

        data: "{noOfAdults:'" + noofAdults.value +  "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (result) {
                     $("#AdultsList").html(result.d);
                 },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                   alert(xhr.status);
                   alert(thrownError);
               }
    });
}
```

**code behind**

```
[WebMethod]
public static string Adults(int noOfAdults)
{
    FlightBooking obj = new FlightBooking();
    obj.CreateAdultsList(noOfAdults);          

    string test= "";
    return test.ToString();
}
private void CreateAdultsList(int noOfAdults)
{
    int n = noOfAdults;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        TextBox MyTextBox = new TextBox();                      
        MyTextBox.ID = "tb" + "" + i;    
        AdultsListPlaceholder.Controls.Add(MyTextBox); //error coming here
        AdultsListPlaceholder.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
    }
}
```

But I receive an error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

What could cause this problem?

Comment: Check out this question and my answer:http://stackoverflow.com/a/7306392/511438

Comment: [check this](http://forums.asp.net/post/4653065.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not dynamically add controls to a page using JQuery AJAX. Please get a good understanding of asp.net page [lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

In short this is how asp.net pages work.

1. Browswer sends request to server. i.e. `http://localhost/test.aspx`
2. Server creates a object for the page class. In this case the class is `Test`
3. The object renders the page. That means it converts the `Controls` of `test.aspx` to HTML which browsers can understand.
4. Server sends the rendered HTML back to Browser and destroys the object.
5. Browser displays the page.

So the server creates a new object every time it receives a page request.

However when a call to `WebMethods` is made using AJAX, no page object is created. This is why `Webmethods` have to be static.

I can see you are trying to create a object yourself and add the dynamic controls to that object. But this object is not related to the content displayed in the browser. So, adding controls to this object won't change anything that's displayed in the browser. For that to happen you have to post the whole page back. And if you return the rendered output of the object you created with `Response.Write`, that will return the HTML version of the whole page. Which is basically same as a `PostBack`

However, you can achieve AJAX based dynamic control rendering using UpdatePanel. Below is one way to do it

**ASPX page**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
             <asp:Button ID="btnCreate" runat="server" Text="Create" OnClick="btnCreate_Click" />
        </ContentTemplate>            
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:Button ID="btnRead" runat="server" Text="Read" OnClick="btnRead_Click" />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</form>
```

**Code Behind**

```
protected int NumberOfControls
{
    get { return Convert.ToInt32(Session["noCon"]); }
    set { Session["noCon"] = value.ToString(); }
}

private void Page_Init(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        //Initiate the counter of dynamically added controls
        this.NumberOfControls = 0;
    else
        //Controls must be repeatedly be created on postback
        this.createControls();
}
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tbx = new TextBox();
    tbx.ID = "txtData"+NumberOfControls;
    NumberOfControls++;

    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(tbx);
}
protected void btnRead_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int count = this.NumberOfControls;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        TextBox tx = (TextBox)PlaceHolder1.FindControl("txtData" + i.ToString());
        //Add the Controls to the container of your choice
        Label1.Text += tx.Text + ",";
    }
}

private void createControls()
{
    int count = this.NumberOfControls;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        TextBox tx = new TextBox();
        tx.ID = "txtData" + i.ToString();
        //Add the Controls to the container of your choice
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(tx);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`AdultsListPlaceholder` is null, you need to override its onload function to create children of this control. 
    e.g.

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
       CreateAdultsList(5);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In asp.net you can not create server control from jQuery or java-script.
Though you can call web-method from jQuery but you can't add any control from web method.
More details
[Add new ASP.NEt server controls with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514835/add-new-asp-net-server-controls-with-jquery)

One of the idea it to create `textbox` is to create html `textbox`

```
<input type="text" id="text1" ></input>
```

And post your value through jQuery ajax for manipulation.

### Edit 1

Other way is to create all the controls at page load (If you know the maximum number)
Hide them initially
Show one by one on button click
And get the value on the server after postback.

Example:
[add text to an asp.net textbox control with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081469/add-text-to-an-asp-net-textbox-control-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing your paradigms. What would you expect this code to do? You can render controls in response to an AJAX call, but you must then manually insert the processed HTML into the DOM.

1. Call server using AJAX
2. [Instantiate a dummy page container](http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2007/11/05/dynamically-render-a-web-user-control.aspx)
3. Render server control
4. Return markup
5. Insert into DOM

Or, you can add new controls in response to a server event via a full postback or an async postback (e.g. an `UpdatePanel`).