# How to append a user control to a list in jQuery

Tags: jquery, webforms, user-controls

I am trying to add a user control to a `<ul>` every time a button clicked

here is what I have

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#btnAddSupplement').click(function () {
        $('#supplementList').append(
                $('<li>').val(<uc1:OrderEntrySupplements runat="server" ID="OrderEntrySupplements" />)
            );
    });
});
```

```html
<ul id="supplementList" style="list-style-type: none">
  <li>
    <uc1:OrderEntrySupplements runat="server" ID="OrderEntrySupplements" />
  </li>
</ul>
<button id="btnAddSupplement" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Add Supplement</button>
```

Comment: haven't you forgot to use either `'` or `"` in your .val() ? Like `.val('<uc1:OrderEntrySupplements runat="server" ID="OrderEntrySupplements" />')`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I did that, but still not working!

Comment: did you use `'` or `"` ?

Comment: check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2jpZjJ9WBfwlOjvr6DYn?p=preview). May it help!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true that you cannot append an user control and that's because it's not rendered directly to HTML.

For example if you have the following user control:

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="ucUserControl1.ascx.vb" Inherits="UserControls_ucUserControl1" %>

<h1>Im an User Control</h1>
<asp:Button ID="btnA" runat="server" Text="Im button A inside User Control"></asp:Button>
```

And include it in your page form like:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">    
   <uc:uc1 id="userControl1" runat="server"/>       
</form>
```

It's going to render like this:

```
<h1>Im an User Control</h1>
<input type="submit" name="userControl1$btnA" value="Im button A inside User Control" id="userControl1_btnA" />
```

The inclusion of the User Control it's clean, there's no `userControl1` in the DOM, just the input that was inside, so you cannot search it through JQuery selectors.

Don't panic There are two workarounds you can still use!

### ClientIDMode

You can use a property of your User Control that sets the ID of the nested child controls (ClientIDMode):

```
<uc:uc1 id="userControl1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID"/>
```

When you set the ClientIDMode of the User Control to AutoID, the rendered HTML looks like this:

```
<h1>Im an User Control</h1>
<input type="submit" name="userControl1$btnA" value="Im button A inside User Control" id="userControl1_btnA" />
```

So the input has a string in it's id that references the User Control!
Now, finally you can do this in your JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#btnAddSupplement').click(function () {
        var elementsInsideUserControl=$("[id^=userControl1_]"); //matches elements with id attribute starting with 'userControl1_'
        $('#supplementList').append(
                $('<li>').val(elementsInsideUserControl);
            );
    });
});
```

### Panel/Div

You can add a Panel/Div inside the User Control as the parent element of the User Control like this:

```
<asp:Panel ID="userControlPanel" runat="server">
    <h1>Im an User Control</h1>
    <asp:Button ID="btnA" runat="server" Text="Im button A inside User Control"></asp:Button>
</asp:Panel>
```

The Panel control renders to a Div so the HTML rendered looks like this:

```
<div id="userControl1_userControlPanel">

    <h1>Im an User Control</h1>
    <input type="submit" name="btnA" value="Im button A inside User Control" id="btnA" />

</div>
```

Finally you can search in your JQuery as you wanted in the first place:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#btnAddSupplement').click(function () {
        $('#supplementList').append(
                $('<li>').val($("#userControlPanel"))//Check for rendered id of panel to search!
            );
    });
});
```

Keep in mind that in this way you cannot import embebed javascript files from the User Control.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the `uc3` was not able to be added, so i changed your code. try this. The style is just for visual effect so you can see it here.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#btnAddSupplement').click(function () {
        $('#supplementList').append(
                '<li><uc1:OrderEntrySupplements runat="server" ID="OrderEntrySupplements" /></li>');
    });
});
```

```css
#OrderEntrySupplements{
height: 10px;
  display:block;
  background-color :#f33;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="supplementList" style="list-style-type: none">
  <li>
    <uc1:OrderEntrySupplements runat="server" ID="OrderEntrySupplements" />
  </li>
</ul>
<button id="btnAddSupplement" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Add Supplement</button>
```

Comment: I am afraid it is still not working. If I append anything else besides the uc it works, but the with uc it does not. 
EX:  '<li>asdfasfaffasdf</li>');
The above code gets added to the list fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to my question will be the same as this one

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6514849/2616000

Fundamentally Impossible. Because my UserControl here is considered an ASP.Net server-side controls